# Matlab: search path locked for editing?

Tags: matlab, directory, search-path

I have written some database management software in Matlab.  Occasionally data is labeled incorrectly and must be moved manually using windows explorer.  All of the folders of the database are in the matlab search path via `addpath(DataBaseRootDir)`.  When one attempts to move or delete a folder in the search path, windows gets stuck waiting for Matlab to stop accessing the folder.

Is there a way to prevent this programmatically?  It is always possible to close Matlab, make chances, and re-open the software but this is sub-ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmpath.html

```
rmpath(DataBaseRootDir)
```

Be aware that like addpath this will only remove the directory, but leave any subdirectories in the path, so if the directory has subdirectories that are also in the path, you would need to remove them as well.

Comment: Is it only possible to solve this by removing the path?  I could add a set of controls to the GUI to unlock and lock the database directory if need be.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood. I thought that it was matlab itself that was stopping windows from copying it by having the file in the observation path. I only have access to a matlab installation in linux, so I thought it might be different in windows

Comment: Windows is stopped by Matlab, but I am wondering if it is possible for the directories in the search path to not be "locked" by matlab.  Individual files can be manipulated at will, but folders in the search path cannot be moved or deleted.